# why should we use html data attributes

Tags: java, html

Let's take this markup for example.

```
    <div id="my_div" custom="some custom value">
    <div id="sec_div" data-custom="other custom value">

    <script>
       let div1 = document.getElementById("my_div");
       let div2 = document.getElementById("sec_div");
       console.log(div1.getAttribute("custom"))// outputs "some custom value"
       console.log(div2.dataset.custom)// outputs "other custom value"
    </script>
```

Similarly, for CSS we can always use attributes for selection

```
 <style>
[data-custom]
{
/* Selects div with id "sec_div" */
}
[custom]
{
/* Selects div with id "my_div" */
}
</style>
```

so my question is  why should we use data attributes instead of directly writing made-up attribute names is using data attributes somehow a better approach

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Fenio why should we use data attributes instead of directly writing made-up attribute names

Comment: Because they are de-facto standardized? https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-data